# How to easily log all disk io in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging, python-os

As the title says, Is there an easy way to log all disk operations using the os library such as `os.remove(...)` and the standard `open(...)`? That includes automatic flushes to files, so just aliasing or overriding the functions used in the code is not enough.

Comment: Python audio hooks https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html ?

Comment: @rasjani it seems to be a little lackluster as it doesn't raise an event for flushing the stream, i can use it for the `os` library for now though. Mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways these could be archived is via Python Audit hooks described in https://peps.python.org/pep-0578/ and the table of actual hooks here https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html#audit-events

As op mentioned, there is no hook to monitor flushes and general writes. However, maybe as extra layer, one could monitor open() calls and attach something like https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/ to explicitly monitor those